# Build a generating function

Tags: combinatorics

Build a generating function for $a_r$ ,the number of integer solutions to the equation

$e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4=r$
$2\le e_i\le 8$

where $e_1$ is even and $e_2$ is odd

The answer I got is $(x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8)(x^3+x^5+x^7)(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)^2$

Can someone confirm this and show me your method in case I am missing something?

Explanation: To generate all formal products of the form $x^{e_1}x^{e_2}x^{e_3}x^{e_4}$ with the given restraints we need a product of four factors, each containing an inventory for $x^{e_i}$ so for $x^{e_1}$  $(x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8)$ is needed since it is even, for $x^{e_2}$ $(x^3+x^5+x^7)$ is needed since it is odd, and then for the remaining factors we need $(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)^2$

Comment: Your GF looks fine.